# How to make two paragraph blocks on same level in wpf, in level wise, keeping one block left align and other right align?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am making a chat window, i just want that message and date time should be on same lign, and same base, there should be no new line in message and date time paragraph block.

[image: chat window example]

```
String loginsays = "\n" + nick+ " says: ";
Run run = new Run(loginsays);

run.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DodgerBlue);

myParagraph.Inlines.Add(new TextBlock(run));

fldoc.Blocks.Add(myParagraph);

Run run2 = new Run(msg);
run2.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);

myParagraph.Inlines.Remove(run);
myParagraph.Inlines.Add(new TextBlock(run2));
fldoc.Blocks.Add(myParagraph);

//(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:tt")
System.Windows.Documents.Paragraph datetime =
    new System.Windows.Documents.Paragraph();
Run rundate = new Run(dt);
rundate.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkGray);
datetime.Inlines.Add(new TextBlock(rundate));
datetime.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Right;

datetime.FontSize = 10;
fldoc.Blocks.Add(datetime);
```

I have made two blocks, one is for chat and other is for date, one is left align, otherone is right align.

Comment: What should happen when the text is so long that it has to wrap? Can it behave like a table or do you want something smarter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could (ab)use a [`Table`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.table.aspx) for that i suppose.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not the exact answer you are after however I think that a `FlowDocument` is not the best UI control for this purpose. I would use a `ListBox` and create an `ItemTemplate` for the `ListBoxItem` which as a grid layout (one row, three columns). Furthermore I would create a class representing a chat message (with properties for who, what and when), hold it in an `ObservableCollection` for all the chat messages and bind it to the `ItemsSource` of the `ListBox`.